# Uploading a file with Selenium from command line input in Python

Tags: python, selenium

```
  1 
  2 import sys
  3 from selenium import webdriver
  4 from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
  5 from selenium.webdriver.common.alert import Alert
  6 from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
  7 
  8 email = sys.argv[1]
  9 file = sys.argv[2]
 10 
 11 print "You're file is " + file
 12 print "You're email is " + email
 13 
 14 driver = webdriver.Firefox("/usr/local/bin")
 15 driver._is_remote = False
 16
 17 driver.get("https://www.ngs.noaa.gov/OPUS/")
 18 assert "OPUS" in driver.title
 19 
 20 upload = driver.find_element_by_name("uploadfile")
 21 
 22 upload.send_keys(file)
 23 
 24 dropdown = driver.find_element_by_name('ant_type')
 25 select = Select(dropdown)
 26 select.select_by_index(591)
 27 
 28 email = driver.find_element_by_name("email_address")
 29 email.send_keys(email)
 30 
 31 driver.find_element_by_name("Static").click()
 32 
 33 #Alert(driver).accept()
 34 
 35 #sys.exit()
```

I have the file in the same directory but when I run I get this error:

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: File not found: uhc30010.15d

But it does print out the correct file when it prints on line 11 so I'm not sure why it cant locate the file

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the full path, e.g.:

```
upload.send_keys(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), file))
```